# Select from another column if selected value is '0' in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the table below

```
id | mainID | subID
1  |   11    |   0
2  |   12    |   0 
3  |   13    |   20
4  |   13    |   21
5  |   15    |   0
```

I need to select all the " mainID " if the subID is 0. If subID is not 0 then select subID instead of mainIdD

Resulting table

```
id | resultId
1  | 11
2  | 12
3  | 20
4  | 21
5  | 15
```

The subID column value is not null so I can't use ifnull here. Can this be done by just using a sql query? And not use write function for it in php. I know it can be done in php but i need this data from the sql query itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select id, (case when subid = 0 then mainid else subid end) as resultid
from t;
```

For your sample data, `greatest()` would also work:

```
select id, greatest(subid, mainid) as resultid
```

Or, if you stored the "0" value as `NULL` instead of `0`, then `coalesce()` would be best:

```
select coalesce(subid, mainid) as resultid
```

If "0" means no matching value, then `NULL` makes a lot of sense.

Comment: can you explain what " coalesce " does ?

Comment: @KuronekoPirate . . . It returns the first non-`NULL` value.  As I say in the answer, it would be a typical solution if `NULL` were used instead of `0`.

Comment: Also I need join another similar table here can I just use the same column to store data of both table?

Comment: @KuronekoPirate . . . .That would be a very different question and new *questions* should not be asked as a *comment*.  You can use the expression in the `JOIN` clause.  Or a subquery so you can directly use the column alias.

Comment: @KuronekoPirate If you need to join another table, please ask another question and accept this answer.